# unexpected value on bit manipulation with macro in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define PTXSHIFT 12 
#define PTX(va) (((uint) (va) >> PTXSHIFT) & 0x3FF)

int main()
{
    printf("0x%x", PTX(0x12345678));
    return 0;
}
```

I tested it on online compiler and I'm getting a compiler error saying `'uint' is undeclared`. I guess C online compiler can't import `stdint.h`. : https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

So I manually put values: `(0x12345678>>12)&0x3FF`.

**Problem** the output is `0x345`, can you explain why?

```
0x12345678 >> 12 = 0x12345 (??)
0x12345 & 0x3FF = 0x345 (??)
```

**UPDATE** Sorry for the confusion guys. 
I'm asking for the explanation on the output 0`x345`. I'm confused why `0x12345678 >> 12` is `0x12345` and `0x12345 & 0x3FF` is `0x345`.

Comment: It includes `stdint.h` just fine. The problem is that there is no such alias `uint` defined to be *in it*.

Comment: `uint` is undeclared because there is no such thing as `uint` in any of the header files... Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: there's nothing to explain: that's the expected & logical result. Instead of `uint` try `unsigned int` or `uint32_t`. Same formula in python gives the same result as well. There's no trick here.

Comment: Are you asking about the build error, or the unexpected output? Please keep it to one question per question.

Comment: What makes you think `0x345` is wrong? What did you expect?

Comment: I'm asking for the unexpected output

Comment: *What* is "unexpected"?

Comment: I thought 0x12345678>>1 is 0x1234567

Comment: @JohnBaek no, the unit of the shift amplitude is _one bit_, not four bits. `0x12345678 >> 4` is `0x1234567`.

Comment: *I thought 0x12345678>>1 is 0x1234567*  `>>1` shifts one *bit*, not an entire hex digit, which is 4 bits.  `0x12345678>>1` is going to be something like `0x9....C`.

Comment: `0x91a2b3c` to be precise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the same result using

```
#define PTX(va) (((uint32_t) (va) >> PTXSHIFT) & 0x3FF)
```

The answer is expected because of the `Bitwise and` operation as mentioned in other answer.

```
      1    2    3    4    5
    0001 0010 0011 0100 0101
    0000 0000 0011 1111 1111
      0    0    3    F    F
AND
    --------------------------
    0000 0000 0011 0100 0101
```

The shift operation is shifting the bits of an unsigned int to the right filling the left with `0`'s.

```
0x12345678

0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000

Shifts by 12


0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 [0110 0111 1000]---->

[0000 0000 0000]0001 0010 0011 0100 0101

  0    0     0    1    2   3     4     5
```

That explains why `0x12345678 >> 12 = 0x12345`

#### Truth table of AND

And if you don't understand the AND operation then it will be the truth table it should know about.

```
A | B | A & B
--+---+------
0 | 0 |  0
0 | 1 |  0
1 | 0 |  0
1 | 1 |  1
```

Comment: He doesn't understand the shift operation either, see his updated question.

Comment: @MichaelWalz.: Yes it seems so that's why added.

Comment: I just misunderstood that hexadecimal represented 0x1 => 0001.  Thanks codrredoc for the concrete explanation

Comment: @JohnBaek.: Yes

Answer (score 4):

What output did you expect?

Let's look the bitwise AND, nibble by nibble, in hex:

```
     1 2 3 4 5
AND      3 f f
--------------
         3 4 5
```

or in binary, which might help:

```
         0011 0100 0101
     AND 0011 1111 1111
     ------------------
         0011 0100 0101
```

It should be obvious that `3 & 3` is `3`, just as `4 & f` is `4` and so on.

Comment: Why is 4&f = 4???? 3&3 is obvious to me.

Comment: @JohnBaek: You are kidding, aren't you?

Comment: I'm just confused. f is 15 and 4 is 4. I haven't used C for 3 years. I'm trying hard to bring it back,

Comment: @JohnBaek it's unrelated to C, you should understand what hexadecimal notation and what bitwise logical operators (and, or) are.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Michael.